# Get AttributeOptions from Magento via SOAP-API V2

Tags: php, .net, magento, soap, proxy

I'm trying to get a list of options for a particular product attribute via the SOAP API.

Using Magento 1.6.2.0 and WS-I compliant SOAP API V2 with .NET

The call is

```
client.catalogProductAttributeOptions(sessionId, attribute.attribute_id, storeView);
```

To get the attribute id i get the attribute with the attribute's code before.
I pass the current sessionId the attributes attribute_id and the storeView.

The interesting thing is that on one magento installation it works fine and i get all the options. 
But on an other similar installation i get following FaultException:

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   MagentoService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPortType.catalogProductAttributeOptions(catalogProductAttributeOptionsRequest
>   request)

EDIT:

One of the Installation i made by myself, this is where i created the .NET Proxy from. Here it works fine. The other installation is the same magento version but installed on an other machine. Additionally there are the Core API Extensions by NETZKOLLEKTIV installed. 
Each installation have different products and categories in its catalogs. Does that make the difference?
Both are set to be WS-I compliant.

Would be great if anybody can give me some hints.
Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between the two installations?

Comment: A bit more info would be great: Are the installations on the same machine? Are they both set to WS-I compliance? Do they have the same products in them?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I edited my question to provide some more Infos. Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned FaultException simply says that the API connection to the Magento Web Server is getting timed out. It may happen due to a long list of Attribute Options for that particular attribute, in this Magento installation.

Try increasing the "`Client Session Timeout (sec.)`" value in the Magento Admin Panel, from:-

- System
- Configuration
- "Magento Core API" Group
- "General Settings" tab

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunatley it does not help. The Session Timeout is now set to a few hours (!) and even with such a big timeout the same "Unkown Error" Fault Exception occurs. I also tried to increase the client side timeouts without success. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @dasheddot - No I'm then extremely sorry, as I don't know any other solution. I can only suggest you that you please start debugging your API call, right from the first line of this API method. :(